# Error in observable, trying to use the method get

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to refactor customised api get, like this:

```
 get( route: string, responseType: RespType = 'json', fullResponse: boolean = false, params = null): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'GET', route, null, responseType, fullResponse, true, params);
  }
```

to this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DocumentCorrespondenceService {

  allCorrespondence: Observable<DossierEntry>;
  correspondenceEntries: Observable <DossierEntry>;
  attachmentEntries: Observable<DossierEntry>;



constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<Array<DossierEntry>> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get( '/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
}

getDossierEntryFileData( entryID: number ): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
  return this.get( '/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryID + '/fileData', 'pdf', true );
}


}
```

But I get now an error like this:

```
Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<DossierEntry[]>'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'DossierEntry[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2322)
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In new Angular versions (inducing an upgrade of typescript version), you have to specify what is the type expected from your http call:

```
getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>( '/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
}
```

N.B: I also changed your `Array` type with `[]`, which is more "javascript like"

Comment: It's not about angular, it's about typescript type checking. You create a getDossier who expect to return a data with type Observable<DossierEntry[]>, so when you're returning the observable it expect to be of that type.

Comment: @Robert Indeed, clarified the reason.